# AngularJS (ng-Click and adding tasks to display-page)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with my TodoList. I'm learning AngularJS and I don't know, how to create `ngClick` function. When I press the "addTodo" button I want to send whole form to another page where I will display the tasks. What do I need to add in ng-click method and the same in todos-data.js.
Here is my code:

todos-data.js ( here, I can add task manually. I want to add tasks from form)

```
app.factory('todos', function () { return [
  {
      'title': 'Randka z Julia', 'done': false, "type": { "name":
      "Personalne", "gico": "heart" }, 'estimates': 3, "date": "11/11/2015"
    },
    {
      'title': 'Silownia', 'done': false, "type": { "name":
      "Zdrowie", "gico": "tint" }, 'estimates': 2, "date": "12/11/2015"
    },
    {
      'title': 'AngularJS nastepne kroki', 'done': false, "type": { "name":
      "Nauka", "gico": "book" }, 'estimates': 4, "date": "14/11/2015"
    },
    {
      'title': 'Spotkanie z Janem', 'done': false, "type": { "name":
      "Biznes", "gico": "usd" }, 'estimates': 1, "date": "15/11/2015"
    },
    {
       'title': 'go runy go', 'done': false, "type": { "name":
       "Personalne", "gico": "heart" }, 'estimates': 6, "date": "16/05/2015"
    }
  ];
});
```

and here is form with button:

edit.tpl.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
<form name="f" data-ng-submit="addTodo()">
  <label for="title">Nazwa:</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="title" name="newTodo" data-ng-model="formData.newTodo" required>
  <label for="type">Typ:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" data-ng-model="formData.type" required>
    <option ng-repeat="value in categories" value="value.name">{{value.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <label for="estimates">Estymowany czas:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="estimates" name="estimates" data-ng-model="formData.estimates" data-ng-options="value + 'h' for value in [] | rangeTime:9:true" >
  </select>
  <label for="text">Data:</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="text" type="text" data-ng-model="formData.date" data-ng-date-picker="" name="date" required readonly="readonly">
  <br />
  <button class="btn btn-success" data-ng-disabled="f.$invalid" ng-click="addTodo()">Dodaj  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: but where you use `addTask`?

Comment: I mean addTodo, sorry for mistake!

Comment: You need to add a controller and define the method addTodo() in it

Answer (score 1):

For this, you should create a controller , in that controller,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.addTodo = function(formData){
         $scope.items = formData;
    }
});
```

And in the page where you want to display it , you can use 'ng-repeat'.

Comment: And how are you getting the data in the correct format in the array? Don't think this will be very helpful for OP.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do something like this in you factory and then define the method in your controller by injecting you factory in the controller.

```
app.factory('todos', function () {
        return {
            todoArr: [{
                'title': 'Randka z Julia',
                'done': false,
                "type": {
                    "name":
                        "Personalne",
                    "gico": "heart"
                },
                'estimates': 3,
                "date": "11/11/2015"
            }, {
                'title': 'Silownia',
                'done': false,
                "type": {
                    "name":
                        "Zdrowie",
                    "gico": "tint"
                },
                'estimates': 2,
                "date": "12/11/2015"
            }, {
                'title': 'AngularJS nastepne kroki',
                'done': false,
                "type": {
                    "name":
                        "Nauka",
                    "gico": "book"
                },
                'estimates': 4,
                "date": "14/11/2015"
            }, {
                'title': 'Spotkanie z Janem',
                'done': false,
                "type": {
                    "name":
                        "Biznes",
                    "gico": "usd"
                },
                'estimates': 1,
                "date": "15/11/2015"
            }, {
                'title': 'go runy go',
                'done': false,
                "type": {
                    "name":
                        "Personalne",
                    "gico": "heart"
                },
                'estimates': 6,
                "date": "16/05/2015"
            }],

            addToList: function (title, done, name, Personalne, gico, estimates, date) {
                this.todoArr.push({
                    'title': title,
                    'done': done,
                    'type': {
                        'name': Personalne,
                        'gico': gico
                    },
                    'estimates': estimates,
                    'date': date
                });
        }
    };
    });
```

Then in your controller

```
.controller("main", function ($scope, todos) {
  $scope.add = todos.addToList;

})
```

Then in your HTML

```
<button ng-click="add(title, done, name, Personalne, gico, estimates, date)">add</button>
```

This is a bit messy with all the parameters passed in. There are better ways to do this. I hope you know how to use ng-model to get all the parameters from a form?